# Storing contents of text file into a char[,] array

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I am trying to get a coordinate system where adjusting the x and y values would determine where to output my char. For example, if my text file had the content:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

When I output array[2,3] = "X", i would get

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 X 9

Currently, my array only stores the first row of the contents of a txt. I want it to display the values 1 to 9 from the text.
 My codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2Test
{

public class Program

{
    public int xLocation;
    public int yLocation;

    public static void Main()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString();
        directory += @"/Maps/Level1.txt";
        char[,] array1 = new char[3, 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j< array1.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                array1[i, j] = (Char)File.ReadAllBytes(directory)[counter];
                Console.Write(array1[i, j]);
                ++counter;
            }               
        }          
    }

}
}
```

Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example `Level1.txt`?

Comment: For now, the text file is just a bunch of numbers as shown above
123


456


789

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read from text file to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835965/how-to-read-from-text-file-to-array)

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems like your text is has more character than your text file. You are iterating over every element of your 3x3 `array1`, but your text file has 11 characters (the blanks count as well).

Here is a dynamic (but very naive) approch:

1. Read the content of the file with [ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ReadAllBytes`
2. [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) the array by the blank sign
3. Iterate through every sign and put it in your map

Source:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString();
    directory = Path.Combine(directory, @"/Maps/Level1.txt"); // Better use Path.Combine for combining paths

    // It is enough to read the text once and not on every iteration
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(directory);

    // In your provided sample the blank sign signals a new row in the matrix
    string[] rows = fileContent.Split(' ');

    // Assuming that it is a matrix, which must always be the same width per line
    // NullChecks ...
    int rowLength = rows[0].Length;
    int rowCount = rows.Length;
    char[,] map = new char[rowLength, rowCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
        {
            map[i, j] = rows[i][j];
            Console.Write(map[i, j]);
        }
        // We are done with this row, so jump to the next line
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```